# Perform any operation in Mysql once it is launched by Terraform. How can I run provisioner for RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, terraform, rds

I have launched an RDS instance using terraform, now I want to create a user and DB inside it, basically, run some query inside it. So how can we achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two options depending on what you want to change.

- You could use the local-exec provisioner.

Basically, you just need to add something like this inside your **aws_db_instance** definition:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "your great command line!"
}
```

Bear in mind that this option has a big limitation, the provisioner will be executed ONLY ONCE after the first time the resource is created.

- You could a specific Terraform provider like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

More info here:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/mysql/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, if you want to run the command based on local file changes is to use a [null_resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) which triggers when your sql has changed.

```
resource "null_resource" "setup_db" {
  depends_on = ["aws_db_instance.my_db"] #wait for the db to be ready
  triggers = {
    file_sha = "${sha1(file("file.sql"))}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "mysql -u ${aws_db_instance.my_db.username} -p${var.my_db_password} -h ${aws_db_instance.my_db.address} < file.sql"
  }
}
```